# When compiling the file, imports are ignored in Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, lerna

I have a component library and I have a main file in the root folder that imports all components and exports them in an object by default, when I ask to compile with Babel I get a JS file with the require of the exported file, what I needed is a single file with all components inside for future access to these components in a static page

first, my index.js with imports:

```
import Button from "../button/src/index";

export { Button };
```

In my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "lerna exec --parallel --scope '@cotabest/components' -- babel --root-mode upward src -d lib",
    "build:bundle": "webpack",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.5",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.9",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.2.0",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-scss": "^1.1.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jest": "^27.4.5",
    "lerna": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.45.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  }
```

I'm working with lerna, but I don't think it's influencing anything.

after, my babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["babel-plugin-transform-scss"],
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  ignore: [
    "**/*.stories.js",
    "**/*.stories.jsx",
    "**/*.test.js",
    "**/*.test.jsx",
  ],
};
```

So the result of the compilation:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
Object.defineProperty(exports, "Button", {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function get() {
    return _index["default"];
  }
});

var _index = _interopRequireDefault(require("./button/src/index"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { "default": obj }; }
```

I would like this output file (post compilation) to have the button component rather than require(relative path), can someone help me?

PS: After that I run the command: "webpack" and create a bundle from the index placing the exported file in a variable through "output.library"